# What does color mastery do?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

In MTG: Puzzle Quest, after playing for a while with a card in your deck you earn "Mastery" over that card. The app tells you this, with a +2  (that is, a symbol of colored mana matching the color of the card). What effect does this have over the card, the deck or your planeswalker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official 1.5.8 Patch notes](https://d3go.com/magic-puzzle-quest-1-5-8-update-arrives/) where this feature was added, there is a full explanation of what Color Mastery is/does:

> **Color Mastery**
>
> We are adding a new major feature, called Color Mastery. In a nutshell, Color Mastery is a point system, per color. Color Mastery is accumulated by mastering cards.
>
> ● You accumulate points on each card in your deck at the end of every fight.
>
> - Only cards in your deck get points, so you’ll want to mix it up to master as many cards as possible!
>
> ● Each card requires different amounts of points to be Mastered ­ few for Commons, lots for Mythics!
>
> ● When you Master a card, you gain points in that card’s color in your Color Mastery chart.
>
> - Colorless cards give you small amounts of points in every color
> - Dual­color cards give you points in both colors
>
> When you enter an event (such as the Nodes of Power event), you will be set in a tier depending your Color Mastery, from Bronze to Gold.
>
> - The event’s color determines which Mastery the game looks at ­ for example, a Blue­-only event would only consider Blue Color Mastery.
> - Events that do not have color restrictions take your entire Color Mastery into account.
>
> Each Tier in an event gives different rewards, and higher tiers give better rewards!